# Which abilities don't share cooldowns?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've noticed that some abilities don't seem to share cooldowns with each other. The various grenade abilities, for instance, and the Vanguard's Nova biotic. The Sentinel's Tech Armor also doesn't cause a cooldown to turn on (though it does to detonate).

Which abilities are off the shared cooldown? What about ammo powers?

Comment: I thought grenades were the only weird ones with cooldowns. Ammo powers don't have cooldowns, do they?

Comment: @BenBrocka It's not much, but it's there. They don't *cause* a cooldown, but they respect it.

Comment: Really? I'll have to test that when I get home. No powers when you're cooling down?

Comment: @BenBrocka Pretty sure. Grenades, yes, change ammo, no.

Comment: @Raven are either one of these answers sufficient to satisfy your question yet?

Comment: @yx. Yeah, I'm inclined to  pick Ben's answer. But why you askin' me? It's your bounty.

Comment: well you haven't accepted an answer yet, it'd be weird to accept one and bounty the other :P

Comment: @yx. I'm waiting for Ben to do his tests about turrets. Rare Candy's info is a little different than his in that respect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's technically three types of powers in Mass Effect: **Active Powers**, **Grenades** and **Passive Abilities**.

Active powers a single [Global Cooldown](http://wikicheats.gametrailers.com/Mass_Effect_3_-_PC_PS3_XB360/Quick_Strategies). A skill either activates the Global Cooldown or it doesn't. Skills that don't activate a cooldown are only limited by how quickly you can perform the action (the time it takes to switch ammo/throw a grenade).

Most powers listed as a [base power](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Powers_(Mass_Effect_3)) here qualify as Active. These are your standard attacks and always cause a cooldown.

Passive powers are always active and don't have cooldowns, simple enough. Ammo powers are technically passive, and you can always switch ammo regardless of cooldown. Tech Armor is basically a passive power unless you detonate it.

Grenades don't use a cooldown either, and if something seems like an "active" power and it doesn't activate the cooldown, that's because it's technically a grenade. Proximity mines, Nova and Sentry Turrets are all technically grenades.

[Nova](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Nova) has a "cooldown" that's actually based on your **Biotic Barrier** (the purple "shield" Vanguards have). You can't use Nova if your Biotic Barrier is empty, but it otherwise ignores cooldowns like a grenade.

Comment: what about Nova, is that a special case?

Comment: And the turrets?

Comment: The Turret is [technically a grenade](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Sentry_Turret) and nova is based off your biotic barrier. Are there any other exceptions I should note? I'm looking through the Wiki

Comment: Nova is *technically* a grenade as well, it's just that instead of drawing off your supply of grenades, it draws off of your barrier.

Comment: Actually I need to test the Turret unless someone else has. I don't have an engineer and I can't quite tell how it works with cooldown from the wiki.

Comment: feel free to go test and update your answer, no rush on the bounty since I can't award it for another 2 days anyway.

Comment: @BenBrocka any further testing results? :)

Comment: So how do you explain that as a Vanguard, I can use Pull and then immediately Charge, while Pull is still recharging?

Comment: @Hitchhiker are you sure Pull is still recharging? Pull has an extremely short cooldown, and when properly upgraded it can be spammed again as soon as the animation is over.

Comment: Definitely, I open the powers menu, Pull is recharging and Charge is available. I have a level 1 pull so its cooldown is not that short.

Answer (score 2):

Ammo Powers do not trigger a cooldown when activated, but cannot be activated when something else is on cooldown.

Fortification, Defense Matrix, and Tech Armor can be turned on without causing a cooldown, but activating their ability (+melee damage, shield restore, explosion) causes a cooldown.

Grenades and Nova are on their own separate cooldown class, and can be freely intermixed with powers. (Nova might require shields, though)

Sentry Turret and Combat Drone (engineer specials) share a cooldown with each other.

Finally, some highly evolved powers have a chance to proc a bonus power, where activating them will not cause a cooldown. (Examples: Tactical Cloak, Charge, etc.)

Comment: Are you sure about the first point? I could switch ammo fine on cooldown. Single player, Vanguard. I'll triple check tonight. I never did get to test Sentries because I haven't unlocked that class in multi.